# WSO2 APIM server doesn't start after changing default DB to MySQL

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I followed the WSO2 documentation (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-databases/changing-default-databases/changing-to-mysql/) to change the default DB to MySQL.
I executed the below steps:

1. Created 2 databases named wso2am_db and wso2shared_db using MySQL 8.0 client.
2. Ran the scripts to create the required tables in both the DB's.
3. Created a user named wso2carbon and granted access on both the DB's.
4. Verified that the DB's, tables and users are created successfully.
5. Made the required configuration changes in deployment.toml file as shown below.

> [database.apim_db]
>
> type = "mysql"
>
> driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
>
> url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wso2am_db"
>
> username = "wso2carbon"
>
> password = "wso2carbon"
>
> [database.shared_db]
>
> type = "mysql"
>
> driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
>
> url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wso2shared_db"
>
> username = "wso2carbon"
>
> password = "wso2carbon"

But on restarting the WSO2 APIM server, I am getting the below error in terminal and the server doesn't start.

[image]

It gets stuck after this message and nothing comes up after this. Am i going wrong somewhere? Need help with this.

[image]

Comment: can u share the complete error trace?

Comment: try restarting your machine and try again

Comment: Hi Vivek, I tried after restarting the machine. Still getting the same error. Do, I also need to change WSO2CARBON_DB to MySQL as given at the bottom of the documentation? I haven't done that as it's written it is not necessary.

Comment: @Suman Normally we discourage linking to paste sites, but I would put your error message into say a Pastebin and link it in comments

Comment: Mysql "Communications link failure" normally means there is an connectivity issue to your database. Can you try the same connection parameters with some other client and verify the connection to the shared_db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be happening due to mutual SSL connection failure when connecting to the SQL server. Can you try out this again with the following configuration in deployment.toml file.

```
[database.apim_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wso2am_db?useSSL=false"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wso2shared_db?useSSL=false"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"
```

Comment: Hi Chamindu, thanks for the above solution. It has worked and server started successfully.